# Wrong resolution at start? HDMI output has to be unpluged and pluged to work correctly

Tags: video, hdmi, display-resolution, vga

every time I start my Ubuntu Studio, after login I can see my desktop, my mouse works but I only see my desktop without nothing, no icons, no bars and etc. I have to unplug and plug my HDMI cable again, than my desktop appears with the monitor settings opened.

Someone knows what is happening and how to solve? I don't wanna lose my HDMI port some day because I have to disconnect and connect it every time with the computer on.

Comment: From the terminal type: `uname -r` what is returned?

Comment: Sounds as if your Ubuntu thinks you have a dual monitor configuration setup as _extended desktop_ and it just shows the _extension_.

Comment: Uname 4.15.0-20-lowlatency


Ubuntu Studio

Comment: @PerlDuck EXACTLY!

Looks like that. But I have only one and I never used a config with more than one. And when I plug the monitor again, it shows only one monitor.

Comment: Have you tried SUPER-P? Like this guy: https://askubuntu.com/q/1093771/504066