# Incorrect behaviour when pressing Super+P

Tags: nvidia, shortcut-keys, multiple-monitors

I have 2 monitors. When pressing Super + P I'd expect the shortcuts to behave like this:

1. Mirror image,
2. Extended image,
3. External only — Only 2nd monitor on,
4. Internal only — Only 1st monitor on.

The first two options work correctly, but the 3rd and 4th options behave very weird: instead of switching one monitor on/off, they change the default monitor to the 2nd one.

Then, I have to launch settings to change my major monitor.